# FTL: How to pass variable in header param in ftl

Tags: spring-mvc, symlink

I have an href tag which is working fine

```
     <a href='<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do"/>'>Forgot ID?</a>
    //My Controller
    @Controller
        public class MyControler{
          @RequestMapping(value=forgotID,method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public ModelAndView forgotIDmethod(@ModelAttribute("model")MyModel model){

       }
```

which is working fine for me

1.Now I wanted to add a param to it I have no  idea how to do it Please help me on this 
My code is

```
    <a href='<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage='loginURL'"/>'>Forgot ID?</a>
    @Controller
       public class MyControler{
                @RequestMapping(value=forgotID,method=RequestMethod.GET)
                 public ModelAndView forgotIDmethod(@RequestParam("loginIdPage")
                String loginIdPage,@ModelAttribute("model")MyModel model){
                   System.out.println(" loginIdPage:-"+loginIdPage);
                }
```

I am not getting the value but 
I got the URL

```
   http://localhost:8084/Login/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=
```

2.Again i tried with  below scenario

```
     <a href='<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=/"loginURL/""/>'>Forgot ID?</a>
```

Getting error in loading the FTL file.

3.When I tried with This

```
     <a href='<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=/'loginURL/'"/>'>Forgot ID?</a>
```

Got the URL like this

```
    http://localhost:8084/Login/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=/`
```

4.When I tried with This

```
    <a href='<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=\"loginURL\""/>'>Forgot ID?</a>
```

Request processing failed; nested exception is found in ftl.

Please help how to process it further

Comment: I am not a expert on FTL, but can you try creating a variable . <#assign hrefUrl = "<@spring.url  "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage='loginURL'/> "> and  use it in href like <a href='${hrefUrl }'>Forgot ID?</a>

Comment: It's an nested tag so got parsing exception.I try this  "<#assign loginURL = "loginURL"/> and <a href='<@spring.url "/forgotID.do?loginIdPage=${loginURL}"/>' /> It is working now Thanks.